# ZLib Decompression in C++

Tags: c++, zlib, compression, gzip

I am trying to get a function going to unzip a single text file compressed with .gz. It needs to uncompress the .gz file given its path and write the uncompressed text file given its destination. I am using C++ and what I have seen is that ZLIB does exactly what I need except I cannot find 1 single example anywhere on the net that shows it doing this. Can anyone show me an example or at least guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to inflate a file with raw deflated data (i.e. no archive) you can use something like this:

```
gzFile inFileZ = gzopen(fileName, "rb");
if (inFileZ == NULL) {
    printf("Error: Failed to gzopen %s\n", filename);
    exit(0);
}
unsigned char unzipBuffer[8192];
unsigned int unzippedBytes;
std::vector<unsigned char> unzippedData;
while (true) {
    unzippedBytes = gzread(inFileZ, unzipBuffer, 8192);
    if (unzippedBytes > 0) {
        unzippedData.insert(unzippedData.end(), unzipBuffer, unzipBuffer + unzippedBytes);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
gzclose(inFileZ);
```

The `unzippedData` vector now holds your inflated data. There are probably more efficient ways to store the inflated data, especially if you know the uncompressed size in advance, but this approach works for me.
If you only want to save the inflated data to a file without any further processing you could skip the vector and just write the `unzipBuffer` contents to another file.

Comment: I found that you may need to call `gzbuffer` after `gzopen` to avoid a `Z_BUF_ERROR`

e.g. `gzbuffer(inFileZ, 32768);` 

Also, make sure you undefine NO_GZIP to ensure the GZIP header check is not IFDEFed out in inflate.c

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`gzopen()`, `gzread()`, and `gzclose()` functions of zlib](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html#Gzip), much like you would the corresponding stdio functions `fopen()`, etc.  That will read the gzip file and decompress it.  You can then use `fopen()`, `fwrite()`, etc. to write the uncompressed data back out.

Comment: Thanks for that. I believe the problem I was facing was that I was using zlib externally by using the zdll1 and linking with zdll.lib although zlib's documentation says it works fine with both 32 and 64 bit applications My application is being compiled with x64 whereas even though it's not specified the dll may have been compiled with x86 and they only have the 1 dll. I get unresolved linker errors for inflate. I will try including zlib inside my project instead of linking to the dll and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: No still getting unresolved symbol errors for inflateInit and inflate even when including zlib internally.

Comment: You'll need to post a different question for help with something as basic as compiling and linking code.

Comment: zlib only has 1 library. I know how to link to libraries and directories. Obviously zlib is garbage so I will be looking elsewhere for another solution.

Comment: @Mark Adler: Obviously he did not realize he was talking to the project's maintainer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ZLibComplete to do this.  There is a complete example in C++ on the front page of GZip decompression.

http://rudi-cilibrasi.github.io/zlibcomplete/

Answer (score -1):

Ah, I'll assume http://zlib.net/zlib_how.html does what you want?

Comment: to be honest with you I read that and walked away even more confused. Mostly as to what the differences were between inf and uncompress and regarding buffer allocation.

Comment: Well, there's a simple source file at http://zlib.net/zpipe.c (linked from that page) and it is 206 lines of code including comments. Not sure you can get much simpler than that, really.

Comment: Mostly what I saw in zpipe.c was decompressing buffer allocated in memory not from a source file to destination file. The reading I have done points me to think that the best way to implement this in C++ is to use one of the many ZLIB wrappers that are floating around. If ZLIB is so straight forward I don't see the reason for all the ZLIB invoked wrappers.